# How can I use the "label" version of List.nth in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

So basically I am writing some OCaml code like this:

```
let p_op p =
Show.show<op> p
|> Str.split (Str.regexp " +")
|> List.nth items 1           (items is the result of Str.split)
|> String.lowercase
```

So the problem is that how can I implicitly pass the result of Str.split to List.nth ?

if I know the `label` of `List.nth`, then I guess I can do this,

```
List.nth ~num:1
```

But basically as I don't use `Core`, I just don't know how to get the `label` of `List.nth` 
could anyone give me some  help?

Then probably I need to wrapper the `List.nth` with labels myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious place to look for this is in `ListLabels`. But for whatever reason the parameters of `ListLabels.nth` aren't labelled!

You can use `flip`:

```
let flip f x y = f y x

... |> flip List.nth 1 |> ...
```

flip is defined in OCaml Batteries Included as `BatPervasives.flip` (and also in Core).

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Yes, actually that's also what I am confused with... thank you and I will do it in this way

Comment: BTW: Do you recommand to use `Core` in substitute of OCaml's standard library..?

Comment: To be honest I don't have a lot of experience with Core. But the OCaml standard library has always seemed too thin to me. A widely accepted enhancement like Core would be fantastic. The book Real World OCaml has made Core the likeliest contender (IMHO).